# Using plotly's hoverinfo: "x+y" with mode: "lines" shows only y values

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm trying to plot a line graph and want the hover info to show the value of *x* and the value of *y*.

My trace has the following properties (among others):

```
  type: 'scatter',
  mode: 'lines',
  hoverinfo: "x+y"
```

The problem is that the hover shows only the *y* value, although I have selected `hoverinfo: "x+y"`.

Note that I would like to show the *x* values without converting them to `text: [x-values]`, which looks a bit hacky.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
hovermode: "closest"
```

to the `layout` variable. Otherwise the coordinates/labels are only shown on the x and y-axis. With `hovermode: "closest"` they are shown next to the closest marker.

```js
var d3 = Plotly.d3;
var N = 25;
var x = d3.range(N).map(d3.random.normal());
var y = d3.range(N).map(d3.random.normal());

var data = [{
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: "scatter",
    mode: "lines",
    marker: {
        color: "rgba(200, 50, 100, .7)",
        size: 16
    },
    hoverinfo: "x+y"
}];
var layout = {
    hovermode: "closest",
    title: "closest"
};

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv1", data, layout);
layout = {
    title: "standard"
};
Plotly.newPlot("myDiv2", data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv1'></div>
<div id='myDiv2'></div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic behind this, but it answers my need. Thanks!